# How to get a flex item to participate in baseline alignment and be centered?

Tags: css, flexbox, baseline

I often run into this issue where there is some extra height coming from somewhere and narrow it down to the baseline of a flex container.

A typical example looks like:

```css
div {
  background-color: #2C3531;
  color: #D9B08C;
}

span {
  background-color: #116466;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
  <span class="container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/400px/218125"/>
    World
  </span>
</div>
```

The problem here is that the baseline of the flex container is the bottom of the image rather than the baseline of "World".

[8.5. Flex Container Baselines](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-baselines) says:

> **first/last main-axis baseline set**
>
> When the inline axis of the flex
> container matches its main axis, its baselines are determined as
> follows:
>
> 1. If any of the flex items on the flex container’s
>    startmost/endmost flex line participate in baseline alignment, the
>    flex container’s first/last main-axis baseline set is generated from
>    the shared alignment baseline of those flex items.
> 2. Otherwise, if the flex container has at least one flex item, the flex
>    container’s first/last main-axis baseline set is generated from the
>    alignment baseline of the startmost/endmost flex item. (If that item
>    has no alignment baseline parallel to the flex container’s main axis,
>    then one is first synthesized from its border edges.)
> 3. Otherwise, the flex container has no first/last main-axis baseline
>    set, and one is synthesized if needed according to the rules of its
>    alignment context.

In the previous example, I don't think there are any items participating in the baseline alignment since `align-items: center`. So rule 1 does not apply.

The startmost flex item is the image and so according to rule 2, the baseline is going to be synthesized from the bottom border.

Swapping the text and image around shows the effect of having a different startmost flex item:

```css
div {
  background-color: #2C3531;
  color: #D9B08C;
}

span {
  background-color: #116466;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
  <span class="container">
    World
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/400px/218125"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

This choice about which flex item the specification says to use seems somewhat arbitrary.

We can make this work by using `flex-direction: row-reverse;` but that's not a general solution.

```css
div {
  background-color: #2C3531;
  color: #D9B08C;
}

span {
  background-color: #116466;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
  <span class="container">
    World
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/400px/218125"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

The last thing I can think of is to give up on centering using flexbox and use `align-items: baseline; line-height: 40px;` instead:

```css
div {
  background-color: #2C3531;
  color: #D9B08C;
}

span {
  background-color: #116466;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  align-self: center;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
  <span class="container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/400px/218125"/>
    World
  </span>
</div>
```

While the baseline is right now, the vertical centering is a bit of a hack and requires height matching which is less than ideal.

Are there any other ways to get a flex item to participate in baseline alignment whilst still being aligned via the center?

Answer (score 2):

Adding an empty element at the beginning should work. You can use the `::before` pseudo-element for this purpose

```css
div {
  background-color: #2C3531;
  color: #D9B08C;
}

span {
  background-color: #116466;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.container::before {
  content: " ";
  white-space: pre;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
  <span class="container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/400px/218125"/>
    World
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you think there is a need to have a bit more control over which flex items participate in the baseline of the container?

Comment: One issue with this solution is that there is an extra column gap between the `::before` pseudo element and the first real item.

Comment: Adding a negative right margin equal to the column gap fixes that.

Comment: You also have to take care to hide any text decoration as that can be applied to the whitespace in the pseudo element. This is more trouble than it is worth when compared to the line height workaround.